# Selenium WebDriver : Not able find xpath for Paytm.com , Proceed button

Tags: selenium, xpath

I was trying to  automate paytm.com site , 
Here i found Proceed button attribute has name but when i tried to use xpath checker for the name attribute , it was showing 13 matches  but my question here is in the webpage from the UI level am not able to see 13 Proceed buttons instead only one Proceed button are present .

Even i tried with other attribute to  find the xpath , but it showing more matches found.

Below is the HTML code for Proceed

```
<div class="msg-container">
<div class="btn-spinner" alt="Proceed to Recharge">
<div class="spinner hidden"></div>
<input class="btn proceed active" type="submit" data-express-text="Recharge Now" data-soft-block-text="Proceed anyway" data-default-text="Proceed" name="Proceed" value="Proceed" alt="Proceed to Recharge">
```

Can you please let me where am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath returns 1 match for me

```
//form[@id='prepaidMobile']//input[@name='Proceed']
```

Also, if want use only `//input[@name='Proceed']` you can get it from List of WebElements:

```
WebElement firstInput = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//input[@name='Proceed']"))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, I think:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='Proceed'])[1]")));
```

Comment: Hi Richard , Thanks for your reply ..I tried  to use the above code but still it is showing 13 matches found ..

Comment: Whether it is an UI designer mistake by providing  not unique name even though they have used name attribute ?

Comment: @user1828754 There's no way that expression would return 13 matches. the entire expression is within parenthesis and the predicate `[1]` selects *only one node from the entire set*. Perhaps you forgot the parentheses?